# Update/set state dynamically in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and used to load/update data through javascript/jquery.

In my example I've got 3 buttons. Whenever I click one one button, I would like to update the text above. Right now, I am using same state for the counter. Can't you somehow get the current divs ID - and update the state inside it?

I could just change the state to 3 different states. 
But the reason why I am not doing this is if I ever want to load something **dynamically** they probably have the same state?

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t9am76fs/1/

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        count: 0,
    };
}
incrementCounter = (value) => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + value })
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id='div1'>
                  <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                  <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter(1)}>+1</button>
            </div>

            <div id='div2'>
                  <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                  <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter(1)}>+1</button>
            </div>

            <div id='div3'>
                  <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                  <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter(1)}>+1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You will need to manage three different states, or maintain a javascript object having three counter values w.r.t to each div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to render dynamic elements, like you would do if you gather data from an API from example.

What I would do is to group the data you need dynamically into an **array of objects**, and you can keep the counter for each of those objects inside the object itself.

In the example below. You map the array and each onClick will update its own object counter. This way you don't need to explicitly write the state for every single element.

This is just a sample and you can improve it later:

```
const dynamicDivsInfo = [
  { name: "Example", id: "div1", count: 0 },
  { name: "Example 2", id: "div2", count: 0 }
];

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      divs: [...dynamicDivsInfo]
    };
  }
  incrementCounter = (value, index) => {
    const divs = [...this.state.divs];
    divs[index].count += value;
    this.setState({ divs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.divs.map((element, index) => {
          return (
            <div id={element.id}>
              <p>
                You clicked {element.name}: {element.count} times
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter(1, index)}>
                +1
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-night-1hfoc?file=/src/App.js:244-1086

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by giving the input names and accessing these via the event.target.name and use that to update state depending on the given name.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: [0,0,0]
        };
    }
    incrementCounter = (event) => {
        const updatedCount = [...this.state.count] // Create a shallwo copy
        updatedCount[Number(event.target.name)]++
        this.setState({ count: updatedCount })
    };

    render() {
    const [count1, count2, count3] = this.state.count;
        return (
            <div>
                <div id='div1'>
                      <p>You clicked {count1} times</p>
                      <button name='0' onClick={this.incrementCounter}>+1</button>
                </div>

                <div id='div2'>
                      <p>You clicked {count2} times</p>
                      <button name='1' onClick={this.incrementCounter}>+1</button>
                </div>
                
                <div id='div3'>
                      <p>You clicked {count3} times</p>
                      <button name='2' onClick={this.incrementCounter}>+1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I do understand it better now!

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count1: 0,
            count2: 0,
            count3: 0,
        };
    }
    incrementCounter = (type) => {
        this.setState({ [type]: this.state[type] + 1 })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id='div1'>
                      <p>You clicked {this.state.count1} times</p>
                      <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter('count1')}>+1</button>
                </div>

                <div id='div2'>
                      <p>You clicked {this.state.count2} times</p>
                      <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter('count2')}>+1</button>
                </div>
                
                <div id='div3'>
                      <p>You clicked {this.state.count3} times</p>
                      <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter('count3')}>+1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you do this without setting 3 states? Asking since I am probably going to load data dynamically in the future.